# What steps should I follow designing a web site?

Tags: website-design, workflow

I'm a web developer with basic skills in Web Design. I'm following a lot of websites containing tips and tutorials how to design.

Can you tell me what steps I should follow from the beginning to the finish when designing a web site? I'm searching for a workflow to accomplish my work effectively.

Comment: Hi sn3ek, welcome to UX.se! As of now, your question is too broad and open-ended. Do you have any particular area in which you need help?

Comment: Please see the [faq](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) and [about](http://ux.stackexchange.com/about) pages, as well as [this question](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-ux-stackexchange) on the Meta site, for ways to ask good questions on Stack UX.

Comment: In addition to all the answers below, an important first step is to consider who your target audience is. What is the demographic, how literate are they, how much time do they have to spend, how likely are they to spend money/scroll/read lots of text/do xyz, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This question is veeeeery open!

I use [Jesse James Garett's method](http://www.jjg.net/elements/pdf/elements.pdf). Its linear enough to explain to your team and keep in mind and enough iterative to fit reality.

For more information read his book: The Elements of User Eperience, a classic.

The steps are basically :

- Take a sheet of paper and think only on your objectives (what you want) and user needs (why people are going to visit your site).
- Take another sheet or a witheboard and list content and functionnalities
- Do some drawings about how all this stuff is going to interact (no details)
- Do some drawings and wireframe pages
- Last part, at this point you can start using your computer : graphics, code and all this stuff people focus on but wich is not important if the former steps have not been completed.

Comment: What do you recommend asking? Because I don't know where to begin to ask.

Comment: I have no idea what is in your mind. Seriously, read the book. Keep in mind that a website is just a mean for people to do stuff. What stuff for what people is the real question.

Comment: I want to become a better web designer. And every website tells a different story about where to start or how to do. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: The reason they all tell a different story is that there are many ways to go about it. It comes down to your needs, your resources, your support and your experience. No single answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a client you need to gather the business needs, goals and get all the content from them. Obviously, you might also need to plan some iterations with the client and plan how and when progress is going to get presented.

Let's assume you don't have a client. The first step is to think about : goals and content.
From there I would advice doing a content tree to see how large the site is. Try to keep it small but complete.

Once you have that think about functionality and how the pages interact with each other. Do some wireframes, drawings, prototypes, whatever you find more comfortable. Don't use color or images to start with. Color and images will only distract you at this stage.

Once you know what is the content, how large the site is, how the functionality works, start doing colored mock ups for the design. Ask other people, leave the computer and come back before you make up your mind, check sites that do similar things to see how the site competes in the web. Make sure this mock ups achieve what you wanted to achieve.

Once you have decided the style (you can only use one page- the most important one and once you are sure you can extrapolate it to the rest of the site), now it's time to define the templates, the grids, the consistency of the site.

Depending on your resources, write the code and start integrating back end and front end (where relevant).

Once you finish do some testing with users, cross-browsing testing and cross-platform testing. If you know responsive design, also test with mobile devices.

And you are all set. Last thing is to set google analytics or some other system to measure the response of the users. That will give you a good idea of what is working and what needs some work on.